# Google Analytics new view with filter shows no data

Tags: google-analytics

I have set up a new Google Analytics view with a filter for monitoring a  tracking traffic to our Italian local site which is located at `domain.com/it/` subfolder. This is how my filter is setup on this view. After 1 week, the view is still not showing any data. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

I have set the filter of the view to include only /it/ subdirectory. This was done according to this [this Blog article](https://www.jeffalytics.com/multilingual-tracking-google-analytics/) advice on how to track multi language websites properly

If I click on verify filter inside filter settings on view, I get this back from Google: **"This filter would not have changed your data. Either the filter configuration is incorrect, or the set of sampled data is too small."**

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without seeing your site and the rest of Google Analytics implementation. Nevertheless, I'll recommend you to try to following implementation:

- Custom filter
- Include
- Request URI
- /it/ (if not working, try to escape it: `\/it\/`)

The screenshot is in spanish but will help you to understand the previous instructions.

[image]

Comment: If you want I can add read only access to you. Nothing to hide there. But following your advice to setup custom filter instead of predefined... What would be the difference anyway? I don't see any difference between my predefined filter and your suggested custom one?

Comment: I never use predefined ones as I want to take control of everything. The filter I mentioned before works for me so it must do it for you as well. Just try it and let us know :)

Comment: By the way, you can check if it's working right now with the Real-Time report.

Comment: Hey I have changed the filter to custom one exactly like you have and I get the same result - no data. Also if I check at real time data I get 0 (see screenshot: https://ibb.co/bx02R9). If I switch to my global view, the one that has 0 filters, and go to real-time view I get the page view which should be included in my /it/ view. See screenshot: https://ibb.co/njOdzU.

Comment: Can you share another screenshot of the filters of this view? and the /it/ filter as well. Also, try to put /it/* just in case...

Comment: Here: https://ibb.co/hpRJip and https://ibb.co/jBdW3p. The /it/ filter is the only filter I have setup at this new view.

Comment: Try escaping the "/": \/it\/

Comment: Yeah this did help... The question is how is it working for you? You don't escape /it/ looking at your screenshot above.

Comment: They must have changed something cause "/" is not a special character needed to be escaped https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en. Moreover, I can assure you mine is working without escaping it (^(/es)?/business/).

Answer (score 1):

If it's a new View with little to no data in it, the filter verification will not work as expected. Filter verification is based on the past 7 days of data in the View and the sample of data may not be enough.

> "This filter would not have changed your data. Either the filter
>   configuration is incorrect,
>
> ***or the set of sampled data is too small***

Real time reports dont always, but can take up to 2hrs to sync with things like newly applied filters.

Other filters applied to the View may also affect how another filter works. Filters run in the order they are applied to a view.

Answer (score 1):

It also can be happened because "WWW" before your domain adress 
Google is sensitive to www 
For example if you put "adress.domain"without "www" on Google analytics and you force members to load the site with "www" like "www.adress.domain" Google won't show anything to you .